# Upload file using selenium python (through shadow root (open))

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

I'm trying to upload file to a website using selenium with the chromedriver.

Unfortunately, I can not do that.

Attaches a picture of the components:

[inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SzUv.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SzUv.png

I tried to execute the following code:

```
input=browser.find_element_by_id('fileInput')
input.send_keys('C:\\picture\\run.gif')
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I also tried using XPATH. But it fails to identify the object.

Does it have anything to do with it being in shadow-root?
What can be done about it? I tried to read about it, but could not write a code that works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It 100% has to do with shadow root

Comment: Can you help me with a code that working?